# How to modifiy a variable inside a $stateParams object from the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the value of one of the properties in the $stateParams object in my controller. I seem to be able to get the $stateParams object as a whole but I can't get a specific property.

```
$rootScope.params = $stateParams;  // this gets me the object
$rootScope.myVar = $stateParams.fooParam + ' some msg'; // this gets me undefined
```

So this is how I setup my $stateProvider...

```
$stateProvider
        .state('parent', {
          url: "/parent",
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
          params: {
            fooParam: 'foo defult',
            barParam: 'bar defult'
          },
          controller: 'ParentCtrl'
        })
```

And then in my html ui-sref route, I pass some stuff to the param.

```
<a ui-sref="parent({ 
        fooParam:'foo parent',
        barParam:'bar parent'
      })">parent</a>
```

Then in my controller I want to access those params. Here is where Is truggle to access members of the $stateParams object.

```
$rootScope.myVar = $stateParams.fooParam + ' some msg';
```

In my HTML if I call {{myVar}}, I just get "undefined some msg"

Basically in this particular example I want to get the value of the fooParam in my controller. I don't understand how to do that.

Here's a Plunker of the example of my issue:

https://plnkr.co/edit/dXTgKMpBTHiv2Bt5nFxC?p=preview

Comment: Updated my answer, with a working plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject $stateParams directly into controller. Change your controller as below.

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams', function($scope,$stateParams)
```

Here is the Plunker
    https://plnkr.co/edit/PVXGjFLMVQdvxUHp1rgs?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was wrong. You do need to include params in the url as below:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent/:fooParam/:barParam",
      params: {
        fooParam: 'foo defult',
        barParam: 'bar defult'
      },
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ParentCtrl'
    })
```

But the other issue is that you need to access $stateParams **from the controller registered for that state**, which is listed in the [gotchas section](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha) of the documentation.

See updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vpL0FJprTbmaDWBVlP4g?p=preview) showing myVar from $stateParams injected in controller  (works fine) and MyVar2 from $stateParams injected in app.run() function (doesn't work).